# How to run ansible plays for some tasks on host when playbook is run via Vagrant provisioner?

Tags: vagrant, localhost, ansible

I am using a Ubuntu 16.04 host with Vagrant installed on it. I would like to log the start time and end time of a set of tasks. These tasks are defined as roles. I created a role **host_test** role to ensure that I am able to `touch` a file on my host using `local_action`. But I believe as this playbook is being provisioned via Vagrant, by the time **host_test** role is played by ansible, Its control is inside the vagrant box rather than outside of it (my intention is to log in the host). So the file is not created on the host.

My directory structure looks like:

```html
goal
├── playbook.yml
├── README.md
├── roles
│   ├── apache
│   │   ├── tasks
│   │   │   └── main.yml
│   │   └── templates
│   │       └── index.html
│   ├── host_test
│   │   └── main.yml
│   ├── mysql
│   │   └── tasks
│   │       └── main.yml
│   ├── package
│   │   └── tasks
│   │       └── main.yml
│   ├── php5
│   │   └── tasks
│   │       └── main.yml
│   └── vim
│       └── tasks
│           └── main.yml
└── Vagrantfile
```

the playbook under consideration can be found at https://github.com/srihas619/vagrant-ansible

Answer (score 0):

Quick search shows that you can use callback plugins (Ansible 2.x+) for that task. The sample timer plugin ([code in official docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#developing-callback-plugins)) is basically a good start if you need something own. Alternatively you can check existing plugins first:
https://github.com/ginsys/ansible-plugins/blob/devel/callback_plugins/timestamp.py

Alternatively, you may simply add

```
callback_whitelist = profile_tasks
```

to your `ansible.cfg` (in `[defaults]`) which would turn on profiler, timestamping each task too:

```
# ansible-playbook install-vim.yml                                              

PLAY [local] *******************************************************************

TASK [install-vim : Install Vim for user root] *********************************
Thursday 17 November 2016  10:23:22 +0000 (0:00:00.037)       0:00:00.037 ***** 
ok: [127.0.0.1]                                                                 

[...]                                                

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=6    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0

Thursday 17 November 2016  10:23:37 +0000 (0:00:01.464)       0:00:15.695 *****
===============================================================================
install-vim : Install Git ----------------------------------------------- 5.06s
install-vim : Install Vim for user root --------------------------------- 4.56s
install-vim : Installing Pathogen --------------------------------------- 1.80s
install-vim : Setup ~root/.vimrc ---------------------------------------- 1.46s
install-vim : Install Solarized theme ----------------------------------- 1.40s
install-vim : Create folders -------------------------------------------- 1.38s
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing this callback feature. I am new to ansible actually. I believe that I am using an ansible i.e., `/usr/bin/ansible` of host machine to provision vagrant guests but, Where can I do a change to my playbook so that I can control some things on my host machine besides vagrant guests?

Comment: There's no guarantee you will get any more attention than you had so far. Also some questions can hang unanswered for long time before someone come with asolution. In mean time you may solve the problem and answer own question etc. In general some Qs attract more ppl, some less. It's crucial to explain the problem clearly, show what have you done etc. Also you may work on your reputation points (answering questions of others etc). So if my answer helps you may i.e. accept it even if it only solved your problem in part. Then you can try to post another question about these unaddressed issues

Comment: Thanks for the Info, Did you completely understand my requirement here? Otherwise suggest me with more requirements so that I can edit the query

Comment: You may need to show some of your playbooks too as the ASCII tree is pretty insufficient for any debugging.

Comment: I have updated my question with example playbook, hope I get some input to continue :)