# running plays on host besides running on vagrant guests when playbook is provisioned via vagrant

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I am new to ansible actually. I believe that I am using an ansible i.e., `/usr/bin/ansible` of the Ubuntu host machine to provision vagrant guests but, Where can I do a change to my playbook so that I can control some things on my host machine besides vagrant guests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Vagrantfile you can define provisioning as:

```
config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
ansible.playbook = "myPlaybook.yml"
```

in this case Vagrant automatically creates an Ansible inventory file in .vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory
that looks like:

```
# Generated by Vagrant
default ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2222
```

so the playbook runs to localhost connecting via ssh to port 2222 and not to localhost as

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
```

If I well understood your problem, you need to run the same playbooks both on Vagrant provided hosts and on your Vagrant host (localhost).

So I think you can assign an ip to Vagrant provided hosts that you are provisioning with Ansible and use a static inventory file you'll supply to Vagrant, so your Vagrantfile will contain something like

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
...

config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
ansible.playbook = "myPlaybook.yml"
ansible.inventory_path = "./myInventory"
```

and in ./myInventory

```
myHost1 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.33.10 ansible_ssh_port=22
```

then you should be able to distinguish vagrant provided host (as it was a remote host) from your localhost. Then you'll arrange your playbook having different targets (myHost1 and localhost) and it should handle correctly local_action.

In your inventory you can define groups as in any ansible inventory file and you could tell Vagrantfile to take care of that supplying ansible.groups

```
config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
ansible.playbook = "myPlaybook.yml"
ansible.inventory_path = "./myInventory"
ansible.groups = { 
"group1" => ["myGroup"]
```

Comment: If I do like that, then I cant do the things with single `vagrant up`. As we are using the host 's ansible there must be a possibility of playing on host as well from the same playbook.

Comment: Can you supply an example about your needs?

Comment: You can find it on my other [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40623847/how-to-run-ansible-plays-for-some-tasks-on-host-when-playbook-is-run-via-vagrant] (question) . Thanks

Comment: Whay not using Vagrant synced folder? You could touch a file in /vagrant (on guest machine) that is shared from your local vagrant box. So you could "forget" localhost in your playbook.

Comment: Yeah. That is perfect. But still, this can be extended to tasks like repackaging Vagrant box. How can they be achieved? I mean after installing certain programmes on the box if it needs to be packaged again. How can I achieve it through the same playbook?

Comment: Not sure I have understood your need. Files in synced folder stay on your server. Running "vagrant up" again the folder is shared again to guest machine and replaced on "vagrant provision". If you need they follow the guest machine, you can copy them in another directory on guest.

Answer (score 1):

To run commands on your local host basically you have two options:

1. for quick stuff you can use `local_action` like so:

`- name: take out of load balancer pool
    local_action: command /usr/bin/some_command`

2. you can hav a collection of tasks in you playbook like this:

`- name: Execute some local commands
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - local_action: command /usr/bin/some_command 
    - local_action: command /usr/bin/some_command`

For more information refer to the very extensive [docmentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html)